# Karma unit testing showing broken UI overlaid in Angular 4.1.3

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm pretty new to Angular and have been building a fun app on the side to get some practice in.

At the moment I'm trying to integrate proper unit-testing and am running into what appears to be some weirdness.

I've build this app using angular-cli and modified the generated unit tests to start fleshing out better code coverage for testing.

However, when running `ng test` the chrome browser then displays some html elements from my apps ui overlaid on top of the karma report. 
[image]

I have a strong feeling this is likely due to me doing something wrong. My google-fu has been less than helpful in this situation. Is karma supposed to try to render the UI at all?

I reduced the testing to purely just a test against my main app.component and even then part of the ui tries to render. In the following code if I remove the reference to PlayerService then UI elements no longer render overlaid on top of the Karma output but of course then the tests fail.

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { PlayerService } from './players/shared/player.service';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavigationComponent
      ],
      providers: [ PlayerService ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

[image]

This seems strange to me.

Full source code can be found here:

https://github.com/joshuahysong/TICompanion/tree/20170606_tests

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A couple ideas here. First, let's get your test working.

"can't bind ngModel to" is a schema error, in this case, input/select. I believe you can fix this with importing FormsModule into the TestBed configuration.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
imports: [FormsModule]
```

Anytime you get "can't bind to" errors, it means your Testbed lacked some way to process a DOM element. If you get into ion-buttons or md-material stuff, you'll see this all the time. Just import those modules into your testbed, and it will know how to process them.

You can also completely forego testing these elements by importing the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA from @angular/core and putting that in your testbed configuration.

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
...
schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
```

Personally, I don't like using this second option. If I'm going to incur the overhead costs of TestBed.createInstance(), then I want to know the template compiles correctly.

Here's a [project](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/testing/ts/app-specs.plnkr.html) by the Angular team that I found super helpful when figuring a lot of this out.

Answer (score 0):

The consensus on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492619/ng5-karma-jasmine-test-renders-component-instead-of-result-page) is that it's expected behaviour. See the answers for possible workarounds.