# Ng5 Karma Jasmine test renders component instead of result page

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Let's say i have a very simple 'create' unit test, kind that `ng cli` generates for you:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'home', redirectTo: '/' }])
      ],
      providers: [SomeService1, SomeService2, { provide: SomeService3, useValue: {} }],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Now when i run this test like so `ng test --browser=Chrome` instead of looking at Karma results page, i am looking at my component.

My CLI version is `1.6.3`, Karma `1.7.1`, Angular `5.2.0`, OS macOS.

**Update** My browser is captured, karma loads, tests run but instead of karma results i see my full-screen component because it's css overlays their results. If i find the div and delete it in the DOM, i can see Karma results.

I was just expecting Angular to remove that node.

Comment: What did make you think that it shouldn't?

Comment: @estus Because if i don't test components i can actually see a page that shows me my tests and success/passes. But if i have this, i don't see that result, i see just my component on top of everything.

Comment: The report is supposed to be observed in Node window (`ng test`). Not in a browser. You won't even have browser window to look at with headless Chrome, for instance.

Comment: @estus yes, i get that on the Ci (we are on PhatnomJS) we get those reported and all is sweet. and i can get the errors in the console locally. But i want to understand why this is happening for component tests and if that is a behaviour that can be controllerd.

Comment: The behaviour you're having is default. It can be controlled by custom Karma reporters, which are defined in Karma configuration. I guess this one would work, https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter

Comment: This issue is valid; I don't have an answer but I can reproduce the issue. Karma states `10% building modules...No captured browser...Chrome 63.0.3239 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 14 DISCONNECTED (10.003 secs / 0 secs)...Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.` so this is not a valid or correct state.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not really sure why the DOM compilation of the component stays after the test ends, but I noticed it happens only for the last test that ran. If you can add another component test that also compiles a component but doesn't add a full-screen component, the previous one is correctly removed. So, simply adding more tests could be the easiest solution.

But if that's not enough, here goes two possible solutions:

### 1. Don't compile it

If your tests don't involve verifying the resulting DOM, you can simplify the arrangement of your test by using the component directly.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // declarations: [MyComponent],
    imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule,
      FormsModule,
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'home', redirectTo: '/' }]),
    ],
    // 1. Add the component as a provider.
    providers: [MyComponent, SomeService1, SomeService2, { provide: SomeService3, useValue: {} }],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  });

  it('should do thing #1', () => {
    // 2. Test it like you would test a service.
    const comp = TestBed.get(MyComponent);
    expect(comp.value).toBe(false, 'off at first');
    comp.doThing1();
    expect(comp.value).toBe(true, 'on after click');
    comp.doThing1();
    expect(comp.value).toBe(false, 'off after second click');
  });

  it('should do thing #2', () => {
    const comp = TestBed.get(MyComponent);
    expect(comp.value2).toMatch(/is off/i, 'off at first');
    comp.doThing2();
    expect(comp.value2).toMatch(/is on/i, 'on after clicked');
  });
});
```

More info [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-class-testing).

### 2. Remove it from DOM

If you do need to test the DOM, the only workaround I have found is to explicitly remove the HTML element after finishing the tests.

```
  afterEach(() => {
    if (fixture.nativeElement && 'remove' in fixture.nativeElement) {
      (fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement).remove();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Removing the fixture.nativeElement in afterEach() solved the same issue for me - I was seeing partially rendered app components in the browser, making it difficult or impossible to see the test results.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `ng test` try running `ng test --sourcemaps=false`

This solved the same issue for me.

It's not a valid state as the comments indicate; Karma reports the following for me which indicates a bad state (you could include info like this in your question next time for clarity):

```
10% building modules...
No captured browser...
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 14 DISCONNECTED (10.003 secs / 0 secs)...
Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.`
```

I was actually unable to see the issue myself - I kept thinking I wrote the test incorrectly. A coworker correctly identified the issue by opening Dev Tools on the Karma browser instance (with the unexpected rendered component). There the console reported the following, which we searched and it led us to the answer:

```
Failed to load ng:///DynamicTestModule/AboutDsloCardComponent.ngfactory.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2956
zone.js:192 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'ng:///DynamicTestModule/AboutDsloCardComponent.ngfactory.js'.
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Users/john.vandivier/workspace/halfaker/usa4-ui/ella-framework/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2956:1
```

Comment: Sorry mate, that didn't change anything. I never had a `no captured browser` issue. My browser is captured, karma loads, tests run but instead of karma results i see my full-screen component because it's css overlays their results. if i find the div and delete it in the DOM, i can see Karma results.

Comment: I get `Unknown option: '--sourcemaps'` error

Comment: @RamiAlloush is looks like the syntax has changed over time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54926842/3931488