# Angular CLI "Unknown option: '--sourcemap'" error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to enable source maps in my Angular-Sass project with these commands:

```
ng serve -sm -ec
ng serve --sourcemap --extract-css
ng serve --sourcemaps=true --extract-css=true
```

However all of them create "Unknown option" errors. None of these flags work.

How can I make this work?

This is the output of `ng --version`:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.0
Node: 8.9.4
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.9
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.0
@angular/cli                      7.3.0
@angular/compiler-cli             7.0.4
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.0
@schematics/update                0.13.0
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.16.4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command is called

```
--source-map=true|false
```

https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: In the referenced link, its `--source-map` and not `--sourceMap` as of 4/21.